# Kendo Grid .NET Core Template with JSON

Tags: json, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I have a Kendo grid template that looks like this...

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AuditDictionaryViewModel>()
 .Name("ConferenceCourseAuditGrid")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
    columns.Template("#:Course.CourseName#").Title("Course Name");
    columns.Template("#:IsDeleted#").Title("Is Deleted");
    columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedBy).Title("Created By");
    columns.Bound(c => c.CreateDateTime).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}").Title("Create Date Time");
    columns.Bound(c => c.UpdatedBy).Title("Updated By");
    columns.Bound(c => c.UpdateDateTime).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}").Title("Update Date Time");
                                                       }).Sortable()...
```

Where it says Course.CourseName...I'm trying to access a nested property on one of my JSON properties. The JSON that I'm getting back from the Network tab looks like this...

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "CreateDateTime": "2020-10-21T10:44:33.6716231-04:00",
        "UpdateDateTime": null,
        "CreatedBy": "hao.nguyen@kizan.com",
        "UpdatedBy": null,
        "ConferenceId": 1,
        "CourseId": 1,
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "Course": "{\"LevelId\":5,\"Level\":null,\"CourseName\":\"Course Name...2\",\"CourseDescription\":\"Course Description...2\",\"IsRequired\":true,\"CreditHours\":2.0000,\"IsElective\":false,\"IsLocallyApproved\":false,\"TreatAsLevel5Elective\":false,\"OtherProvider\":false,\"NameProvider\":\"\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"IsCharterCourse\":false,\"IsNewCourse\":true,\"MandatoryTrainingTopicId\":null,\"MandatoryTrainingTopic\":null,\"MandatoryCheck\":false,\"CharterTopicCourses\":null,\"TopicCourses\":null,\"ConferenceCourses\":null,\"CreatedBy\":\"unknown\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"CreateDateTime\":\"2020-10-19T15:48:40.8230887\",\"UpdateDateTime\":null,\"Id\":1}"
    }, {
        "CreateDateTime": "2020-10-21T10:44:34.7188373-04:00",
        "UpdateDateTime": null,
        "CreatedBy": "hao.nguyen@kizan.com",
        "UpdatedBy": null,
        "ConferenceId": 1,
        "CourseId": 3,
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "Course": "{\"LevelId\":null,\"Level\":null,\"CourseName\":\"Course Name...4\",\"CourseDescription\":\"Course Description...4\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"CreditHours\":0.5000,\"IsElective\":true,\"IsLocallyApproved\":false,\"TreatAsLevel5Elective\":false,\"OtherProvider\":false,\"NameProvider\":\"\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"IsCharterCourse\":false,\"IsNewCourse\":false,\"MandatoryTrainingTopicId\":null,\"MandatoryTrainingTopic\":null,\"MandatoryCheck\":false,\"CharterTopicCourses\":null,\"TopicCourses\":null,\"ConferenceCourses\":null,\"CreatedBy\":\"unknown\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"CreateDateTime\":\"2020-10-19T15:48:40.8230887\",\"UpdateDateTime\":null,\"Id\":3}"
    }, {
        "CreateDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "UpdateDateTime": "2020-10-22T14:46:28.5255395-04:00",
        "CreatedBy": null,
        "UpdatedBy": "hao.nguyen@kizan.com",
        "ConferenceId": 1,
        "CourseId": 2,
        "IsDeleted": true,
        "Course": "{\"LevelId\":null,\"Level\":null,\"CourseName\":\"Course Name...3\",\"CourseDescription\":\"Course Description...3\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"CreditHours\":3.0000,\"IsElective\":true,\"IsLocallyApproved\":false,\"TreatAsLevel5Elective\":false,\"OtherProvider\":false,\"NameProvider\":\"\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"IsCharterCourse\":false,\"IsNewCourse\":false,\"MandatoryTrainingTopicId\":null,\"MandatoryTrainingTopic\":null,\"MandatoryCheck\":false,\"CharterTopicCourses\":null,\"TopicCourses\":null,\"ConferenceCourses\":null,\"CreatedBy\":\"unknown\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"CreateDateTime\":\"2020-10-19T15:48:40.8230887\",\"UpdateDateTime\":null,\"Id\":2}"
    }, {
        "CreateDateTime": "2020-10-21T10:44:34.7188373",
        "UpdateDateTime": "2020-10-22T14:46:29.0453815-04:00",
        "CreatedBy": "hao.nguyen@kizan.com",
        "UpdatedBy": "hao.nguyen@kizan.com",
        "ConferenceId": 1,
        "CourseId": 3,
        "IsDeleted": true,
        "Course": "{\"LevelId\":null,\"Level\":null,\"CourseName\":\"Course Name...4\",\"CourseDescription\":\"Course Description...4\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"CreditHours\":0.5000,\"IsElective\":true,\"IsLocallyApproved\":false,\"TreatAsLevel5Elective\":false,\"OtherProvider\":false,\"NameProvider\":\"\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"IsCharterCourse\":false,\"IsNewCourse\":false,\"MandatoryTrainingTopicId\":null,\"MandatoryTrainingTopic\":null,\"MandatoryCheck\":false,\"CharterTopicCourses\":null,\"TopicCourses\":null,\"ConferenceCourses\":null,\"CreatedBy\":\"unknown\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"CreateDateTime\":\"2020-10-19T15:48:40.8230887\",\"UpdateDateTime\":null,\"Id\":3}"
    }],
    "Total": 4,
    "AggregateResults": null,
    "Errors": null
}
```

The other columns show up fine, but retrieving the nested properties from Course doesn't work. I think I need a way to escape the quotes from the nested property or something in order to get that value?

Comment: Your json looks suspect. The property names within Course have the quotes escaped which is not the case on those properties one level up. Are you getting undefined showing for it in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

The `Course` property seems to be an encoded JSON, try to decode it:

```
columns.Template("# let course = JSON.parse(data.Course); ##: course.CourseName#").Title("Course Name");
```

A better approach is to use DataSource's [`schema.parse` event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.parse). Create a [custom DataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/helper-basics/custom-datasource) like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Custom()
        .Schema(schema => schema
            .Parse(@<text>function (data) {
                data.forEach(item => item.Course = JSON.parse(item.Course));

                return data;
            }</text>)
        )
    )
)
```

Then you can use `columns.Template("#:Course.CourseName#")` on your template.